# Hiding some user profiles temporary from search

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm trying to find a way to hide a user profile in SharePoint temporary from the People search result.

What are the possible solutions?

Is it possible for me to set some kind of crawl rule to skip some user profiles based on a flag? or Can I lock a user profile?

Thanks,
Siriwat

Answer (score 0):

Do not know what do you mean saying lock a use profile!
I prefer the first one, just add crawl rule. It is not different at all.

Comment: It seems that setting crawl rules is working fine with content. But, I don't know how to set a crawl rule for user profile.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can delete the user from the
   import source (AD, LDAP etc) and
   then recrawl.  That will remove him
   (although thats more permenant than
   anything)
2. Depending on how good your
   XSLT is [you can edit the
   results](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms584121.aspx) and you should be able
   to throw in an statement that looks
   at the username and show everyone
   but that user.
3. You can also remove the user
   programatically and recrawl,
   however, I'm pretty sure the user
   will show up again per the profile
   import schedule, which you can delay for however long you need to hide this user.  I would put the code here but stackoverflows editor is absolutly abysmal.  [Give this blog post a shot.](http://sridharu.blogspot.com/2008/03/delete-user-profile-programatically.html)

Personally I recommend option 2 as you have the most control there, no need to compile anything, and no need to muck around with the SSP.

Answer (score 0):

If the solution is temporary then go for editing the XSL template, If you want to remove the user permanently then add the crawl rules to exclude the specific user.

For removing a single user, adding a rule and re-crawling the AD will not scale up an also an added burden to your indexer.